# oracle clob export/import across non linked instances

Tags: oracle, migration

I'm trying to migrate table data across two instances(different instance schemas, but same table schema) that are not connected(not an option).

The problem is that I can not access host file systems and the table has large number of rows with CLOB data(with newlines of course).

TOAD exports with delimited text, insert statements, SQL loader(automatic TOAD script, not custom fitted) and MS Access has failed so far; TOAD either refuses or does't fill CLOB cells.

Is there any way to do this without buying specialized software or splitting CLOBs into mutiple rows and assembling them later?

Also I'm limited to the following:

Oracle db: 10.2.0.4.0

client: 9.2.0.1.0

TOAD: 9.6.0.27

If anybody has any ideas, it would help a lot, thanks!

Comment: You might want to try this (JDBC based) tool: http://www.sql-workbench.net It has it's own "copy" command: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-copy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the legacy (but still supported) [`EXP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_export.htm#BABBHCIE) utility to export a table/schema/DB to your local computer, and then use [`IMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/original_import.htm#i1023560) to import the data on another instance.

Comment: Thanks, I have found out that TOAD even has GUI wrapper for this utility.